# Vue multiple checkboxes with binding in component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I get how to bind multiple checkboxes to an array in Vue. But when I try to put the checkboxes into their own component and bind to an array using v-model it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any idea why?

CheckboxSelection.vue

```
<template>
  <div  v-for="(check,index) in checks" :key="index">
    <input  v-model="model"
            :value="check.value"
            :id="check.id"
            type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: Array
  },
  data(){
    return {
      model: this.value,
      checks: [
        {
          id: 1,
          label: 'Check 1',
          value: 'check1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Check 2',
          value: 'check2'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    model: function(val) {
      this.$emit("input", val)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<CheckboxSelection v-model="selection"></CheckboxSelection>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue 3 `value` prop has been changed to `modelValue` and the emitted event `input` to `update:modelValue` :

```
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: Array
  },
emits:["update:modelValue"],
  data(){
  ....
  },
  watch: {
    model: function(val) {
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", val)
    }
  },
}
```

for the script setup syntax please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738073/8172857)

Comment: I've just realised that clearing the bound value (in my example called 'selection') does not clear the checkboxes states (though the modelValue seems to be empty) - do you know a solution to that?